# `iframe` inside an HTML table

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am displaying some data from a database into my cms, using tables (`tr`, `td`).

```
   <tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post_image; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post_title; ?></td>
        <td>
            <iframe width="100px" frameborder="0" id='inneriframe' scrolling=yes >
                <?php echo $post_description; ?>
            </iframe>
        </td>
        <td><a href="index.php?edit_football_news=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="includes/delete_football_news.php?delete_football_news=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Unfortunately the description php variable is not displayed at all inside my `iframe`. However, if I take out the `iframe` tag, everything works fine, and I can see all the stored values from the database.

```
<tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post_image; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post_title; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $post_description; ?></td>

        <td><a href="index.php?edit_football_news=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="includes/delete_football_news.php?delete_football_news=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
```

So my main question is how to use iframes inside `td`s?

Comment: There is only 1 'good' advice I can give you: stop using iframes.

Comment: iframe requires a source https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe - Yours has none.

Comment: if you had a look at your HTML source, you'd of seen that the content's there. ^ Nobody's paying attention here. `<?php 

$post_description =  "desc";

?>

           <iframe width="100px" frameborder="0" id='inneriframe' scrolling=yes >
                <?php echo $post_description; ?>
            </iframe>` there, echo'd in html source `<iframe width="100px" frameborder="0" id='inneriframe' scrolling=yes >
                desc            </iframe>` but NOT on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iframe` elements load external documents; the HTML that goes between their start and end tags is *alternative content for browsers which **do not support** iframes*.

If you want a scrolling area on a page, apply [the CSS `overflow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to an appropriate element (probably a `div` in this case).

Comment: yes I want to to apply a scroll area,instead of having the massive text which is stored in the database.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comments (but gotten no response from).

- iframe requires a source `src="file.xxx"`.
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Taken from example #1:

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="400" height="300">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

What you need to do is to remove the `<?php echo $post_description; ?>` from the iframe and just do:

```
<iframe src="file_for_iframe.php" width="100px" frameborder="0" id='inneriframe' scrolling=yes >

</iframe>
```

and have the variables inside `file_for_iframe.php` to be echo'd in there.

That's how you'll get your iframe to show the contents "on screen" rather than in HTML source.

If you had a look at your HTML source as I also mentioned in comments, you would indeed have seen the contents.

They're in there alright, but not being echo'd properly (on screen).

The (and as an example) `file_for_iframe.php` file that I have stated above, will contain whatever content you wish to display.

For example:

```
<?php 

echo $post_description = "Whatever is presently assigned to this...";

?>
```

**Important note:**

`echo $post_description = "x";` is valid syntax and you need to keep the echo for it. Otherwise, it won't work.